# MySQL One to Many relationship exlusions based on criteria

Tags: mysql, database

Consider the following.

I have a table with RecipeComponents , which has a one to many relationship to Ingredients.

I want the names of recept_navn from table Recepter which do not include the Raavare champignon.

Recept has a one to many relationship with receptkomponent. One recept has many receptkomponents.

Receptkomponent has a one to many relationship with Raavare.
A Raavare is included in multiple receptkomponents.

Initially i thought i would just select and join the three tables and make a where clause for raaavare_navn != Mushroom.
Since it is a one to many relationship and the RecipeComponent table contains multiple ingredients, i'll end up deleting the row with mushroom, but the RecipeComponent will still show up in rows with the other ingredients

Here is what i tried to do at first.

```
SELECT DISTINCT recept.recept_id, recept_navn
FROM recept
JOIN receptkomponent ON recept.recept_id = receptkomponent.recept_id
JOIN raavare ON raavare.raavare_id = receptkomponent.raavare_id
WHERE raavare.raavare_navn != 'champignon'
GROUP BY recept_id
```

DATA:

```
Tablename: Raavare
raavare_id    |    raavare_navn    |    leverandoer
___________________________________________________
1             |    dej             |    Wawelka
2             |    tomat           |    Knoor
3             |    tomat           |    Veaubais
4             |    tomat           |    Franz
5             |    ost             |    Ost og Skinke A/S
6             |    skinke          |    Ost og Skinke A/S
7             |    champignon      |    Igloo Frostvarer
```

Tablename: Receptkomponent

```
recept_id     |    raavare_id    |    nom_netto    |    tolerance
__________________________________________________________________
1             |    1             |    10.0         |    0.1
1             |    2             |    2.0          |    0.1
1             |    5             |    2.0          |    0.1
2             |    1             |    10.0         |    0.1
2             |    3             |    2.0          |    0.1
2             |    5             |    1.5          |    0.1
2             |    6             |    1.5          |    0.1
3             |    1             |    10.0         |    0.1
3             |    4             |    1.5          |    0.1
3             |    5             |    1.5          |    0.1
3             |    6             |    1.0          |    0.1
3             |    7             |    1.0          |    0.1
```

Tablename: Recepter

```
recept_id    |    recept_navn
_____________________________
1            |    margherita
2            |    prosciutto
3            |    capricciosa
```

Comment: Your image links don't help much, because they show a result set, not the original tables, and the ingredients are in some language other than English.  Please _edit_ your question, show sample data (in English), and the output you want.

Comment: Could you post your mysql queries please?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i added some images to better show my problem.
recept_id = 3 is the only recipe which contains the raavare champignon (id 7).
I want to return the names of all the recept_navn where the recept does not contain the raavare 'champignon' (ID 7).

In my original question you can see the query i tried to use which obviously doesnt work because of the one to many relationship. Essentially i join the three tables and remove based on the row that includes the raavare champignon. Then 2 rows remain with the recipe capriccosa because it consist of two other raavare's.

Comment: Still unclear.  Neatly include all relevant data directly in your question.  Do not paste image links.

Comment: Updated the post to include the relationship between the tables and the data of the two tables. Hopefully this is useful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer.

First you want to make a query that selects all the recept_names with the raavare 'champignon'.
Then you make a query that selects all recept_names where the previous query is not in.

```
SELECT DISTINCT recept_navn
FROM recept
WHERE recept_navn NOT IN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT recept_navn
    FROM recept
    JOIN receptkomponent
    ON receptkomponent.recept_id = recept.recept_id
    JOIN raavare 
    ON raavare.raavare_id = receptkomponent.raavare_id
    WHERE raavare_navn = 'champignon'
)
```